# Sort Silverlight DataGridComboBoxColumn by DisplayValue

Tags: silverlight, datagridcomboboxcolumn

I have SL DataGridComboboxColumn. I have set the SortMemberPath same as the DisplayMemberPath; and the sort doesn't happen. If I set the SortMemberPath same as ValueMemberPath, sort happens. But I need the sort to work as per DisplayMember.
I tried

```
        Public Function CompareTo(obj As Object) As Integer Implements System.IComparable.CompareTo
        Return Me.Name.CompareTo(CType(obj, Person).Name)
    End Function
```

No Luck :(

Any help ??

TIA.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem.  From the research I have done it is because the underlying CollectionViewSource is doing the sorting, and the CVS has no idea about any Display Members of the combo columns (only the value members / foreign keys), therefore it cannot sort by that field.

The only solutions I have come up with is to add a ReadOnly property (AutoGenerateField:=False) to the grids datasource, but this is a rubbish solution.

I am amazed how little this problem is reported, hopefully someone has a better solution...